# Unable to post .json file in jira

Tags: json, bash, jira, jira-rest-api

I am unable to POST .json file when added with directory link.

```
curl -s -D- -u uname:pword -X POST -d ${dir}@story_sp2.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://jira.local.com/rest/api/2/issue/"
```

Error message:

```
{"errorMessages":["Unexpected character ('/' (code 47)): maybe a (non-standard) comment? (not recognized as one since Feature 'ALLOW_COMMENTS' not enabled for parser)\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@1632e5dd; line: 1, column: 2]"]}
```

But I can able to POST .json file without directory link

```
curl -s -D- -u uname:pword -X POST -d @story_sp2.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://jira.local.com/rest/api/2/issue/"
```

Comment: What's the content of `$dir` ? Do you get the same results if you use double quotes like so ? `"${dir}@story_sp2.json"`

Comment: @Aserre dir="/home/arun.srinivasan/script" im using this $dir a location of json file. and yes, im getting same error when use double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of your -d is incorrect. The '@' should be before '${dir}'. It was also mentioned in this KB - https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/unexpected-character-thrown-when-trying-to-perform-rest-calls-771895041.html.

Hope this helps.